# Wordpress filter search results up to a certain date

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to filter the front-end search results up to a certain date in the past? For example, only show posts that have been posted in the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use the `pre_get_posts` filter hook and write a function that modifies the search query:

```
function restrict_search_results($query) {
  if ($query->is_search) {
    // modify $query here
  }
  return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'restrict_search_results');
```